# Developing a Firefox plugin/addon that invokes "Save As" from FF's own set of functions

Tags: firefox-addon, xpcom

I have a basic FF addon that polls for something in the DOM of the page in window.document. When it sees it, it is supposed to save the page.  That's the hard part. I don't want to replicate the functionality of "save complete" I just want to call the pre-existing functionality from the plugin/addon at the right moment.

Is this an XPCom thing?  Or is it pure JavaScript via the relevant APIs ?

[iMacros for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox) can invoke Save-as (without popping the associated dialog), but I can't see how.

Can anyone advise as to how to call deeper Firefox functions like this?

Thanks,  - Paul

PS - I really love [Mozilla Archive Format, with MHT and Faithful Save](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozilla-archive-format/) but I think it is replicating functionality again.  My alternative is to invoke it's function, but that's as opaque to me as the firefox native one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use nsIWebBrowserPersist.saveDocument() for this:

```
var persist = Cc["@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1"].
  createInstance(Ci.nsIWebBrowserPersist);
var localPath = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].
  createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile);
localPath.initWithPath(pathToLocalDirectory);
var localFile = localPath.clone();
localFile.append("mylocalfile.html");
persist.saveDocument(document, localFile, localPath, null, 0, 0);
```

The key is the third parameter which specifies where the linked URIs should be stored. See http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla2.0/source/embedding/components/webbrowserpersist/public/nsIWebBrowserPersist.idl#256 for complete documentation.