# Save full page in Firefox as HTML complete web page from a custom button

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am developing a Firefox's button that performs several actions I use to do frequently in a sequence. One of the actions is to save the web page as HTML, but implementing this action is creating difficulties for me. This functionality is already implemented in Firefox: you can access it through "File" -> "Save Page As" -> "Web page, complete". However, I did not find the way to call that functionality from the code of my own button. Maybe the answer is in https://searchfox.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/content/contentAreaUtils.js, but I cannot see it.

The answer at [Developing a Firefox plugin/addon that invokes "Save As" from FF's own set of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605377/developing-a-firefox-plugin-addon-that-invokes-save-as-from-ffs-own-set-of-fu) seemed promising, but it seems to be old and I could not make it work.

Any tip is welcome.